# Network Error AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError, at Axios.request, and at async getUsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

[Everything is fine when at code editor but when I run it on localhost it become like this, is there any solution that can helpful? There's no error at code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El20C.png)

I try to make CRUD in my project fullstack. I hope this error can be fine and find something helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: without *code* the answer is a pineapple

Comment: paste your code here to let us see whats the problem.